# Dynamically upload an image

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

is it possible to retrieve an image from the database and show it in the upload field of a form?

For example :

I could retrieve a name from the database and display it on the form like this :

```
{{ Form::text('Location', $variable->name, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'placeholder'=>'Location', 'readonly' => 'readonly')) }}
```

Can I do the same with an image? I have tried this :

```
{{ Form::file('Photo', $variable->photo, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
```

but I get error : Illegal string offset 'name'. Any ideas?

Comment: You can display image by using <img> tag. I'm confused what you intend to do.

Comment: What I intend to do is, instead of clicking the choose file button then select an image to upload, I want the image selected dynamically from the database.

Comment: For security reasons, html will not let you preset the value of a file form element. Also, it actually contains (on the client side) the path/filename on the client's machine, so you can't set it to a value that would make sense.

Comment: got it..my scenario is, I have two users, one uploads an image into a table. The other needs to approve that image and post in on the front end of the website. How can I make this possible?